# Starting Python program from windows-start changes the path (os.listdir)

Tags: python, windows

I have a program called `DnD.py` that uses `os.listdir()`.

I would like to run such a program pressing `Windows Key` and writing `DnD` which correctly and instantaneously finds the right program, but `os.listdir()` has a completely different return when the program is launched that way.

I want the same return as I get when I start `DnD.py` from file explorer.

Also, this program should be able to run regardless of its absolute path. If I move the folder containing it I want it to still work. So `os.listdir(HARDCODED_CURRENT_PATH)` will not work.

Edit: Essentially, I would like to find the path to `DnD.py` regardless of where was it launched from.

Then I can do `os.listdir(PATH_TO_DND)` and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir(sys.path[0])`

Will return the contents of the folder that the ran script is in.

from [**sys.path**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path):

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.